# javascript timer to display the time ticking since an order was placed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, timer

I am bulding a tool which tracks online orders. For this I am setting up a admin page where the orders will be listed in a table.

Since I get as many as 200 to 300 orders in a day and the time it takes to deliver each order is around 60 minutes to 12 minutes, I want to include a java script timer which displays the time since the order was placed by the customer.

This is how it works: 
The customer places an order on the website. This is reflected immediately on the admin's orders page. Let us assume the order was placed at 16:00 pm and has a order number 1001. Now there should be a column in the orders table that displays the time since the order was placed **which is updated every second automatically**. So when the admin view the order table at **16:15pm**, the time displayed by the "**time since ordered**" column should be **00:15 mins**. 
when the admin view the orders page at **16:16pm** the time displayed by the "**time since ordered**" column should be **00:16 mins**. and so on.

Once the order has been successfully delivered to the customer, **the admin will go ahead and close the order. After the admin closes the order it should display the time it took to complete that order. This we can get calculating the difference between the "the time the order was placed" and "the time the admin closed the order.**

Now the timer is displayed individually for every record that is getting entered to the order table.

My order table will look something like this:

### Order no.   Date and Time         Time since Ordered   Order details       OT   Status

1001        19-Aug-2013 16:00pm    00:15mins             manchow chuiken    -     Pending

1002        19-Aug-2013 15:15pm    60:00mins             Fried noodles      -     Pending

1003        19-Aug-2013 15:15pm      -                   Chcken winglets   30mins Delivered

If you notice the **first two records** the status is still pending so the "**time since ordered**" keeps ticking until the status changes to delivered. On the **third record** the "time since ordered" field is blank as the delivery has been made. However it displays the "**OT**" as **30 mins**. This means the admin has updated the order to delived 30min after the order was placed.

Please help me in achieving the above explained. I know that I need to implement JavaScript to display the Time ticker.

My questions are: 
How do I keep each row independent? each row should display the appropriate "time since ordered" ticker.

Irrespective of the admin refreshes the page or logs out of the admin page or what so ever, the time ticker should keep running until the admin updates the record to delivered. How can this be achieved?

I would like to use AJAX for the table so that the new records gets added automatically. How do I do this?

Kindly share your view. I can provide more clarity if I have confused the concept.

Thank you 
Hareesh

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Surely you've at least come up with the html structure for your table?

Comment: The "Time since Ordered" column, If you add that and you update that every minute, there will be lot of update queries on that table for sure. Say on a very good day you got over a 1000 orders. Iam sorry to say with these many update queries it will slow down the execution also there is no surety that the time inserted/updated is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping it

**Order no. | Date and Time | Order details | OT Status | Order Delivered Time**

As soon as an order is placed, record the date and time in **Date and Time** Col

While displaying this order, find current time , calculate time difference between current time and time order was place. Display this time difference. This would be static.

To make the time difference go down with every second on that page start a javascript countdown timer. You can get help making one

And finally when the order was delivered save the delivery date and time in **Order Delivery Time** so that you know in how much time order was delivered also change OT status to 'delivered' but that you are already planning to do.

Comment: Thank you somuch you inputs

Comment: Vaibhav - 

Thank you somuch for your inputs. I have found a way to calculate the time difference. More or less it sounds like what you hae suggested. 
The issue however is the table will be refreshed for every 10 secs to update new orders automaticaly. When this happens, the javascript timer gets resetted back to 0 every time the pages refreshes or the timer starts from the previous orders time. 

Displying the time dynamically(for every indiviual oder) seems to be a problem